# FileUpload ASP.NET control not working under Windows 7

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, windows-7, internet-explorer-8

I have a User Control that contains a `System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload` control as well as a button to 'Submit'.

When the button is clicked code similar to the following is executed:

```
If FileUploadControl.HasFile Then
   'Save the file and do some other stuff
End If
```

This code works just fine with Windows XP.  However, if I run it from a Windows 7 64-bit machine using IE8 32-bit the `HasFile` property always returns `false` and nothing is saved?!

Any suggestions/ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had such problems with `FileUpload` control as well (not specifically with Windows 7). Try checking `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileUploadControl.FileName)` instead. I don't know if it will help in your particular case, but I it worked for me.